# Python selenium clear words

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a question about long words.
I have a form word: TestAutomationInProject.

I must clear this word and write new: TestAutomation

I know how I must clear this words, but it is not completely removed
I get, for example, "TestAutoTestAutomation". How to do (without time.sleep) to wait until everything is deleted and then write?

My code:

```
name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("path-element")
name.clear()
name.send_keys("TestAutomation")
```

Comment: Have you stopped the average time of clearing the field? It´s normal on selenium to wait after interactions.

Answer (score 0):

**This will give you an idea:-**

By using Explicit wait in selenium you can make wait your programe-

```
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id('someId'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem:

```
 name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("path-element")
 name.send_keys( Keys.CONTROL + "a" )
 name.send_keys("TestAutomation")
```

In this case the whole content of the input field is selected and overwritten with your value "TestAutomation"

Comment: Before : name.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "A")
Should I use  name.clear() ?

Comment: No, is not necessary.

Comment: @Mateusz Nerkowski   Did you succeeded to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, but I need change because this resolve don't use in my class